# Google ad cannot find a responsive size in non-fixed width div

Tags: html, responsive-design, adsense

I am having issues getting an adsense ad to appear in a non-fixed width div. Basically, I have two divs sitting side by side, I would like to have the Google ad appear in the second one, which doesn't have a fixed width set. See my sample code:

```
<div style="width:1000px">

<div style="float:left; width:200px">
test
</div>

<div style="float:right; overflow:hidden">
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
 style="display:block"
 data-ad-client="ca-pub-1234"
 data-ad-slot="5678"
 data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
</div>

</div>
```

Google refuses to serve an ad, however, instead I get the following error: "Cannot find a responsive size for a container of width=0px"

Any ideas how this can be solved? Thanks!

Comment: Have you done a search? There's plenty of questions with the same problem. And many of them have been solved in one way or another.

Comment: Yes, I've searched - the fact that I have two divs beside each other makes this one more specific than it seems. And I've tried setting a timeout or using onload for calling the ad, but that didn't do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I ultimately ended up using this solution:

[Cannot find a responsive size for a container of width=0px and data-ad-format=auto adsense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25810361/cannot-find-a-responsive-size-for-a-container-of-width-0px-and-data-ad-format-au)

...which I thought was just a workaround, but it appears like feeding Google actual widths is the (only) way to do it.

From the source (Google): If you place your responsive ad code within a parent container that doesn’t have an explicit width set, for example, within a floating element, then our ad code won’t be able to calculate the required size for the responsive ad unit. In this case, you’ll need to modify your code and use CSS media queries to set the size of the parent container.

PS: To center the ad properly, if you're using the linked-to solution, put "margin:auto" in the .banner class.